# How to change node shape and colour in ggraph

Tags: r, ggraph

The first image is a hand drawn image and the second image is the same graph drawn using ggraph. 
[image]

This is the code that generates the graph.

```
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggraph)

V <- read.table(text = "x        y
                2 1
                4 2
                4 4
                2 5
                6 4
                3 7
                8 6", 
                header = T) %>%
  rownames_to_column("name")

E <- matrix(c(0,    1,    0,    0,    0, 0, 0,
              0,    0,    1,    0,    0, 0, 0,
              0,    0,    0,    1,    1, 0, 0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 1, 0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 0, 1,
              0,    0,    0,    1,    0, 0, 0,
              0,    0,    0,    0,    1, 0, 0), nrow = 7, byrow = T) %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  rename_all(list(function(x) 1:7)) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "from") %>% 
  gather(to, val, 2:6) %>% 
  filter(val == 1) %>%
  select(from, to)

nodeLables <- c(" I ", " N0", "F", "N1", "N2", "F1","F2")

g <- graph_from_data_frame(E, vertices = V, directed = F)


ggraph(g) + 
  geom_edge_link(edge_width = 1.3) + 
  geom_node_label(aes(label = nodeLables),label.r = unit(0.75, "lines"), 
                  label.size = 0.65, label.padding = unit(0.55,"lines"), show.legend = F) +
  ggtitle("My plot") +
  coord_flip() +
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +

  # Using scale_x_reverse and swapping the limits
  scale_x_reverse(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(9, 0), breaks = c(0:9), minor_breaks = NULL) + 
  # switching y position to "right" (pre-flip)
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),limits = c(0, 9), breaks = c(0:9), minor_breaks = NULL, position = "right") +
  theme_minimal()
```

In the second graph the nodes are not prefect circles and the curvature changes with the size of the label. I want to make the nodes perfect circles and assign colours for different types of nodes. For example

```
I - Blue
F - Red
Nx - Green
Fx - Orange
```

I've played around with geom_node_point and geom_node_text and got the below result. However, I can't increase the node size further. **How can I increase the node size?**

```
nodeColours <- c("blue", "green", "red","green", "green", "orange","orange")

ggraph(g) + 
  geom_edge_link(edge_width = 1.3) + 
  geom_node_point(aes(size = 4), color = nodeColours)+
  geom_node_text(aes(label = nodeLables))+
  ggtitle("My plot") +
  coord_flip() +
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +
  scale_x_reverse(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(9, 0), breaks = c(0:9), minor_breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),limits = c(0, 9), breaks = c(0:9), minor_breaks = NULL, position = "right") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have to set `size` outside `aes`, that is `geom_node_point(size = 4, color = nodeColours)`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thanks. Have been fighting with the code for hours! Thank you.